# Maximum amount of time I can spend in France and not be considered a fiscal resident

Tags: taxes, residency, non-residents

I would like to know what the maximum amount of time I can spend in France and not be considered a fiscal resident.   I rent a house full time but do not live in France full time or file taxes in France as I am a US resident. I do pay the local taxes d'habitation which has to do with the rental tax on the house I rent.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a rule that spending more than 183 days a year in France makes you a fiscal resident :
[Résident fiscal en France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9sident_fiscal_en_France)

But it is more a rule of thumb than a law.

The [French tax website](http://www.impots.gouv.fr/portal/dgi/public/popup?espId=1&typePage=cpr02&docOid=documentstandard_6069) lists some points that make you a fiscal resident :

- your 'home' (*foyer*) (meaning partner, childs, ...) is in France,
  even if you travel a lot.
- you have a professional activity in France
- your main economic interests take place in France (business,
  investments, ...)

There's one mysterious sentence on this page :

*Dans certains cas vous pouvez être imposés en France si vous disposez directement ou indirectement d'une ou plusieurs habitations dans notre pays.*

In some cases, you can be taxed in France if if you benefit directly or indirectly of a housing in our country.

(although that might refer to the *Taxe d'habitation)*.

Comment: Thanks audionuma, I rent a home for the moment and will next year be paying a taxe d'habitaion But have no financial interests in France. It looks like I might need to find a professional international tax consultant for a definitive answer. All the documentation I have found is very ambiguous!!!! And as an American the laws that apply to UK residents won't apply for me… Thanks for you answer!!!!

Comment: When in France, if you do speak french or can be helped by a french speaker, you can have a free appointment at your Centre des Impôts to get more information from the tax administration.

Comment: Thank you I will call to make an appointment to see what information They can give me.